# Removing version of task group through REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I have made a Preview version of a task group. Now, I want to remove that version. So, not making it a full version, but delete it so the previous version will become the latest again.
As there is no way in the GUI to remove it, I thought the REST API might work.
First, I did

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/{taskGroupId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

From the resulting JSON, I removed one version. Then, I posted it back to Azure Devops like:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/{taskGroupId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

That results in an error however:
"The request specifies task group ID  but the supplied task group has ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000."

The documentation shows a sample without the taskid in the URL, but that also results in an error.

I have tried to change the contents of the JSON with new version and time, but I still get the same error.
Any ideas if this scenario can work? If so, what should be changed?

Regards,

ThyS

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not available.

Check [Unable to delete a newer version of task group in Release manager
Closed vsts](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/401397/unable-to-delete-a-newer-version-of-task-group-in.html), it says *" This is working as designed. We cannot delete a new version of task group."*.

I've also tried the [Taskgroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and it seems can only update rather than deleting/removing a version of task group.

Anyway, deleting/removing a preview version of task group is not available at current time.

Comment: Hi @ThyS, although the answer is "it's not available", it's still the answer for the question at least for the current days. You can [accept it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helps. Thanks!